# boost::condition_variable wait without a lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Is it possible to "wait" on a boost::condition_variable without having to acquire a mutex lock first? Failing that, can this be done using the pthread lib directly somehow?

For simplicity I'd like to avoid going directly to the OS layer (such as futex on linux). But I also don't want the overhead of the mutex call.

*I'm quite aware of the race conditions doing this under normal circumstances. I have that covered in another fashion.*

Comment: If you look at the usage pattern of boost::condition_variable, it doesn't really make sense for it to be used without a mutex. Upon entry, the wait method atomically unlocks the mutex and adds the thread to a waiting queue, and later locks the mutex when it returns :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mutex must be acquired first in both case.

From [boost.threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) documentation :

> void
>   wait(boost::unique_lock&
>   lock)
>
> **Precondition: lock is locked by the
>   current thread** [...]

From [pthread_cond_wait](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) man page :

> The pthread_cond_wait() and
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() functions are
>   used to block on a condition variable.
>   **They are called with mutex locked by
>   the calling thread or undefined
>   behaviour will result**.

I'm not aware of any alternative.

Comment: Alright, so definitely a no go with this system. I'll have to look for something else.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. As you can see from the `condition_variable` API specs it always needs to be provided with a lockable packed in a `unique_lock`. But I don't really understand where the problem is. This construct implements a a "monitor", which can't be done without some kind of synchonization object...